# How to adjust table column width by dragging in ng-zoro?

Tags: angular, ant-design-pro

I'm trying to make my columns resizable by dragging, but its not getting resized properly. The columns are mapped like parent and child. if i'm trying to drag the child the parent is getting resized . how to resolve this issue